# How to hide the third nested list in this css dropdown nested lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I successfully created this not so bad css-only dropdown. I'm trying to hide the `.submenutwo` so that it is only visible when `.submenu` is on hover. If we can do this with css only that would be nice. But if javascript or jQuery can help it's fine.

```css
/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */

.navigation {
  min-width: 300px;
}
/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */

.mainmenu,
.submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}
/* add hover behaviour */

.mainmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #C5C5C5;
}
/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
      display the submenu inside it.
      we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
    */

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
/*
      we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
      CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
    */

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}
/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */

.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}
/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
      we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
    */

.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Apples</a>


      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Green Apples</a>

          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Oranges</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Option 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Option 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Option 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Grapes</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Purple Grapes</a>

          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Green Grapes</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Red Grapes</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.submenutwo {
    display: none }

.submenu:hover .submenutwo {
    display: initial }
```

Here's how you can do it in css. Basically, what's happening here is. At first, you just need to hide `.submenutwo`. After the hover triggered, you just need to bring back the display to the default or even other display value will do.

Answer (score 1):

> may be this will help u

```css
/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */
.navigation {
  min-width: 300px;
}
.submenutwo {
    display: none }

.submenu:hover .submenutwo {
    display: initial }
/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */
.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */
.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}

/* add hover behaviour */
.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}


/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
  display the submenu inside it.
  we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
*/

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  min-height: 200px;
  height:auto;
}

/*
  we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
  CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
*/

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}

/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */
.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}

/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
  we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
*/
.submenu {
 
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
  <li><a href="">Apples</a>


    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Green Apples</a>

        <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a></li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a></li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Oranges</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Grapes</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Purple Grapes</a>

          <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a></li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a></li>
            <li class='listOptionLvlThree'><a href="#"> Option 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Green Grapes</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Red Grapes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```